# UE5 EOSPlus ReadFriendsList Error EOS_Connect_QueryExternalAccountMappings EOS_InvalidParameters

Tags: unreal-engine5

developing using UE5 and EOS

testing using EOS Plus at the moment, I have logging in working fine now with steam and EOS (just as a test), my steam account is linked to my epic games account, however when I call the ReadFriendsList api with the code below (and many variations of this code to make sure it wasnt just me)
[image]

I get this error message

LogTemp: Warning: bWasSuccessful: 0

[2022.05.09-07.27.24:370][800]LogTemp: Warning: ErrorStr: EOS_Connect_QueryExternalAccountMappings() failed with result code (EOS_InvalidParameters)

I have all the below settings turned on
[image]

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I reported the bug with Epic Games EOS Team directly, looks like this is a bug that may have been introduced 6 months ago, it is with the devs and should be fixed soon

for reference this was not working as of the UE5.0.1 and UE5.0.2 updates so anyone in future can get a time reference